# How to access user's profile photo from Microsoft graph API and display React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access the user's profile picture using [Microsoft's Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0). The following is my code to fetch the profile image :

```
export async function getprofilePhoto() {
  const accessToken = await getToken(loginRequest);
  const headers = new Headers();
  const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers,
  };

  return fetch(graphConfig.graphMePhotoEndpoint, options)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response != null && response.ok) {response.blob().then((data) => {
          if (data !== null) {
            window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            return window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
          }
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error("Profile image not found");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw new Error("Profile image not found");
    });
}
```

In my react component I pass on the returned data from the above function but it never renders the image. The code for my component looks like:

```
<Avatar
 alt={name}
 src={profileImage}
 className={classes.avatarMain}
 />
```

The profileImage is the returned data from getprofilePhoto() method. I can also see a request in network tab to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value` with success response with image
but it never shows up in my component.

Can someone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: The code started working after I appended this "Content-Type", "image/jpeg" to headers.

Comment: Hi can you show your getToken method? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: I get a 401 when I call the endpoint. Should I make any changes in my app registration?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I had send one more header(key/value) which is `"Content-Type", "image/jpeg"` and code started working